# What were the demands of satan before coming to this world as lucifer

Tags: quran, hadith, shaitan

When Satan was being sent to the world, he asked Allah for a place to reside, and he requested to be allowed to dwell in the empty space in the human body. Allah had made it easy for him until the Day of Judgment, so his request was granted, and he was given a place in the human chest cavity.

Need reference to this statement